# Get variable value from terraform cloud

Tags: terraform, terraform-cloud

I have data result:

```
test = [
      + {
          + category  = "terraform"
          + hcl       = false
          + id        = "var-1adsJ88M"
          + name      = "myValue"
          + sensitive = false
          + value     = "keys"
        },
      + {
          + category  = "terraform"
          + hcl       = false
          + id        = "var-WcFasdas1"
          + name      = "potoken"
          + sensitive = false
          + value     = "b6adasd222gt5Nh("
        }
       ]
```

How to get value a specific name.

Example: I need get value from of name myValue. This name can be in any position, I need to search the array

My attempts:

```
output "variables_cloud" {
  value = data.tfe_variables.test.variables[*].name == "myValue"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to search iteratively:

```
locals {
    test = [
           {
               category  = "terraform"
               hcl       = false
               id        = "var-1adsJ88M"
               name      = "myValue"
               sensitive = false
               value     = "keys"
            },
           {
               category  = "terraform"
               hcl       = false
               id        = "var-WcFasdas1"
               name      = "potoken"
               sensitive = false
               value     = "b6adasd222gt5Nh("
            }
           ]
           
    value_found = [for a_map in local.test: a_map.value if a_map.name == "myValue"][0]
}
```